# Are most US mass shooters Democrats?

Tags: united-states, criminology, guns, demographics, statistics

Are most mass shooters Democrats? This representative said they are.

['So many people that commit mass murders are Democrats': New York congresswoman sparks outrage during discussion on Florida school shooting](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-5420171/Republican-congresswoman-Many-mass-murderers-Democrats.html):

> 'Yeah, well, obviously there is a lot of politics in it, and it's interesting that so many of these people that commit the mass murders end up being Democrats, but the media doesn't talk about that either,' Tenney told talk show host Fred Dicker without providing evidence to support her claims.

Objective question: What percentage of US mass shooters in the last 50 years are registered Democrats?

Here is a [partial list of mass shootings](https://www.motherjones.com/politics/2012/12/mass-shootings-mother-jones-full-data/). It left off [Plano, TX, 8 killed](https://www.dallasnews.com/news/crime/2017/09/10/8-reportedly-shot-death-plano-home-suspect-killed-police). It also has shootings with only 3 fatalities, while mass shootings are generally defined as 4 fatalities (not including shooter). If that list was consistent, why didn't they include the [Ohio baby party 'mass shooting' with many injured but only 1 fatality](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4682816/911-calls-reveal-chaos-fatal-shooting-OH-baby-party.html)?

Comment: https://www.snopes.com/democrat-shooters-list/ Looks like snopes has already looked at this.

Comment: So, unanswerable? "Verifying this information through online state voting registrations proved problematic as deceased individuals are removed from these databases. We reached out to state historical societies for additional documentation, but several of the states we contacted told us that voter registration records weren’t archived. "

Comment: Either there is evidence (and the list is therefore either correct or incorrect) or there is no evidence (and the list is statistically irrealistic). In either case the question seems answerable.

Comment: Another factor here:  Shooters tend to be young.  Young people tend to be Democrats.  Even if there is a pattern you have to check this before drawing a conclusion.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Do you have evidence? [The Las Vegas shooter was 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Paddock). The [congress baseball shooter was 66](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Congressional_baseball_shooting#Perpetrator).

Comment: These Twitter images state somewhat related claims, but are very small samples and may be cherry-picked.

[Twitter image one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qBF9.jpg), 

[Twitter image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVsoN.jpg) 

It turns out one of the lists was debunked by Snopes.

Comment: Kind of a weird question. Politically motivated shooters are by definition domestic terrorists. Yet we know plainly that a good proportion of shooters have/had no apparent political motivation, thus their political affiliations would seem irrelevant. Only that subset of political motivated shooters should be considered here, if the goal is to determine whether a disparity exists in breeding domestic terrorists.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is little evidence upon which this list is based, even after
extensive searches, and many of those records seem to be inaccurate, or
later corrected.

To quote Snopes:

> We searched contemporary reports for each of the listed incidents in
> an attempt to uncover any mentions of political affiliations,
> motivations, or voting records. Many of these items can be traced back
> to poor reporting, articles that were later corrected, or fake news
> items. And although we encountered this meme (or a similar list) on a
> variety of web sites, none of these publications provided any
> documentation to back up these claims.
>
> Verifying this information through online state voting registrations
> proved problematic as deceased individuals are removed from these
> databases. We reached out to state historical societies for additional
> documentation, but several of the states we contacted told us that
> voter registration records weren’t archived. Even if they were,
> however, one’s official party registration can often contradict one’s
> political beliefs.
>
> Given the difficulty of finding the political affiliation of many of
> the individuals on this list, we are highly skeptical that this list
> is based on credible information.

Source: [this Snopes article](https://www.snopes.com/democrat-shooters-list/) which examines the claim in considerable detail.

The Snopes article goes through the 20 claims one-by-one. One can refer to Snopes for the details, but net-net is that Snopes rated one item "mostly true" (Lee Harvey Oswald), eight items "false" or "mostly false", and 11 items as "unproven". In general, the "unproven" decision was due to a lack of any hard evidence as to the political affiliation of the shooter.

I'll add the historical observation that, between roughly 1900 and 1964 the Republican and Democratic parties almost exactly switched sides philosophically. So claims that someone was a Democrat in the 1800s, (the Lincoln and Garfield assassinations), is essentially a claim that they would be a Republican by today's standards.

Relevant to this historical observation:

[Is it true that Jim Crow laws were primarily promoted by the Democratic Party?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/54399/is-it-true-that-jim-crow-laws-were-primarily-promoted-by-the-democratic-party)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115220/discussion-on-answer-by-daniel-r-hicks-are-most-us-mass-shooters-democrats).